# How can I send Emails from my EMmail ID though PHP page?

Tags: php, html, email

I am creating one construction website in core PHP. It is almost done.But now I want to add one page which can send E-Mails.My "TO"section will be editable but the "FROM" section will be the same for every time..How can I implement this?

Comment: Addition- If the sending fail..the user should get failure message..Can anybody help?

Comment: I have searched from php manual and also searched from www.w3school.com.but can't get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved my PHP and HTML combination.. Let me brief you on the same/ 
Have email.php page which has to from and msg text fields. Make your FROM section will always be the read only mode. And have submit button "SEND" this is  call your email_tranfer.php where you will receive all these POST params and send email by using mail() function of php. And same can be done in AJAX way also..

Thanks 
Gururaj.

Comment: I know the basics of AJAX..but every time it scares me while implementing...I will try for the first one.....

Comment: What do you mean by 'Make your FROM section will always be the read only mode'?

Answer (score 1):

This best way is to use phpmailer class.

[PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

Comment: Can it will give me the error message back if the other party won't get mail due to some technical or connection problem...?

Comment: yes it will return 1(true) if mail sent or 0(false) if mail fails.

Comment: Great..so i just have to set alert message for success or failure by checking flags right?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `mail()` function where the headers (in particular `From`) are hardcoded/included. See example #2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Comment: So  you are saying thatin From section I should pass my Email ID as string..?

Comment: Your email address... yes. So something like: `$headers = 'From: me@my.email.com' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Can it will give me the error message back if the other party won't get mail due to some technical or connection problem...?

Comment: Hey Zoran119 ..I need to do this..Suppose I am sending mail and close my website..Now due to some problem my mail couldn't reach to other party....so whenever I open my website again...It should give me the error message....Is it possible?

Comment: Well, it kind of can. From the manual: "Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise. It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination." So you will get an error if the mail server doesn't accept the email for delivery (your headers are malformed for example), but there will be situations where `mail()` will return true and the email is not delivered (I'm not sure, but I think that one situation where this would happen if the email address doesn't exist).